# Segment mesh based on vertex colors. Vertex Colors / Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, vertex-colors

How would one segment or divide a large complicated mesh based on vertex colors.  I have some large mesh files that were generated from a point cloud and the color data does a great job of showing where I need to divide this mesh up.

Are there any geometry nodes that could enable something like this?

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.

Comment: You could do that with a script, but it's tricky. if you select a face and limit vertex painting to selection, you will see that each vertex can have as many colors as the number of faces it belongs to. If you imported the mesh, then good news, those vertices will be split for you. 
Geometry nodes would create an overhead in this case that could even impact performance if the meshes are heavy enough.

Comment: related: [Splitting object into multiple parts, performing operation on them, then joining them back using geometry nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/291806/60486) Here instead of position you would use vertex color. If you make the separation discriminator change per frame, then on each frame you can duplicate the object and apply the modifier, or automatically use python to evaluate the object and save it as a copy.

Comment: Thank you so much for the replies everyone.  I will upload an image today.  I think my main concern is the size of these mesh files and the face count.  These were created in Sequoia utilizing its reduce face count feature, but even then, reducing to the lowest amount possible while maintaining forms is still a super heavy mesh file.  When I post images I will include detailed stats.  Thank so much!!!!