# How to handle the huge point cloud with Geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, point-clouds

I am working with the geometry nodes to handle some amount of points generated.
However, blender becomes very slow when the points amount is big.
I am thinking if I can handle the points batch by batch. For example, by applying the geometry nodes for part of the points and start another geometry node to repeat the process. However, it is not quite effective and I wanted to do it within one geometry node or automatically by the geometry nodes. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It's hard to advise anything, considering how laconic your question is. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/291820/60486

Comment: Hi. There is very little information here. What do you mean by "huge point cloud"? 100,000 points? 1 million points? 10 million or 100 million? What becomes slow? The viewport? The render time? Or is the processing of the geometry nodes slow? How do you display/render the points? Have to tried to reduce the number that are displayed? What does your GN with the point cloud? How do you handle them batch by batch? Sorry, this question can not be answered...